# x86 Assembly program runs poorly under VirtualBox (XGA Graphics - VBE)

Tags: graphics, assembly, x86, virtualization

I'm trying to understand how virtualization is affecting my x86 assembly program.

Normally I boot up an old clunker pentium III and boot DOS off a USB key. Instead I tried setting up virtual box, and working that way. **My programs seem to run fine, but the colors appear to be all screwed up.**

It's a fairly straightforward program assembled under NASM that switches the video mode into XGA 4105h and draws some simple shapes in varying colors.

Is it safe to assume that the issue stems from the fact that the ACTUAL video mode of my machine isn't *really* running in XGA mode, so the bits for the colors are interpreted differently? (forgive the ignorance in explanation, as I know little about how virtualization works on an ISA level)

How might I get around this issue? I'd like to continue to do x86 graphics programming, but I like being able to work mobile.

EDIT: I see that at least under windows, when trying to execute 16-bit code, windows runs in a virtualized environment that doesn't give the program direct video-card access, but instead gives access to a "virtual card" which typically doesn't extend beyond VGA...

But because I am already in a virtual environment, how does that play into this? Am I totally hooped?

Comment: Yes - I receive similar results in DosBox

Comment: Have, you tried a more modern real PC. The 4105h (mode number?) is quite big, and i think only a few lower numbers are standardized.

Comment: Tried this solution on a very new Lenovo laptop with similar results.

Comment: Post the minimal code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4105h is a standardized VBE modenumber for a VBE 1 bios and also for the DOSBOX. But starting with VBE 2 the mode numbers are not longer standardized. With a VBE 2 or VBE 3 bios we have to get the modenumbers from the card bios, if we do not use the DOSBOX.

For to get these mode numbers from a VBE 2 or a VBE 3 bios we have to use the VBE function 4F00 for to get the VBE SVGA information in a buffer of 512 Bytes. Inside of this buffer+0Eh we can find the address (OFFSET, SEGMENT) of the modelist and with this address we can get the modenumbers. The modelist ends with the word of 0FFFF.

Also if we use the DOSBOX, with each modenumber we can get the mode specific information with VBE function 4F01h in an other buffer of 256 Bytes. Now we can check the mode attributes, the resolution, the bytes per pixel, the bytes per scanline, the fild position and the mask size of the red, green and the blue color and other criteria, if they comply the requirements we are looking for.

Dirk